# What is el() function? ReferenceError: "el is not defined"

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am writing a block in wordpress gutenberg but wordpress showing el( is not defined?
my edit: function is

```
edit: function( props ) {
    function onChange( event ) {
        props.setAttributes( { author: event.target.value } );
    }

    return el( 'input', {
        value: props.attributes.author,
        onChange: onChange,
    } );
},
```

how to include el support in my plugin ?

Comment: Wherever you originally copied the code from, there `el` is most likely defined as  `var el = wp.element.createElement;` and you most certainly forgot to copy that shortcut, or it is not defined in the same scope where `el( 'input', `  is used.

Comment: Yes i understand @t.niese you save my time

Answer (score 0):

You should define `el` first which contains the block element.

```
var el = element.createElement;
```